# Can I use frequency hopping spread spectrum technique for audio steganography?

Tags: matlab, frequency-domain, spread-spectrum, steganography

I have been trying to use spread spectrum technique for audio steganography. I read a lot about it.But i didn't find any information about the steganography scheme using FHSS(frequency hopping spread spectrum). Isn't it possible to do steganography in .wav files using FHSS?

Comment: Of course it's possible. You can call anything steganography that doesn't occur to the observer and can transport information. But I guess you already knew that. So, why don't you simply spend a couple of minutes developing a proof-of-concept to discuss?

Comment: Whether FHSS for a pretty non-flat channel like typical audio channels is a good idea, or if doing FHSS has any advantages over just modifying least significant bits of your audio samples following any other pattern is a completely different topic, though. I'd presume plain FHSS work relatively bad over real-world audio channels,nor over audio compression/decompression,and I'd also assume that you'd normally never transmit uncompressed WAVs anywhere.So,"possible" and "sensible" are two things,and you should describe the steganography application you're trying to build,at least from end to end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to hide data inside audio files using FSSS technique. Have a look at this [publication](https://www.academia.edu/18075721/Spread_spectrum_audio_watermarking_using_frequency_hopping_and_attack_characterization) and [this one](http://journal.telfor.rs/Published/Vol4No2/Vol4No2_A15.pdf).

Since *HAS (Human Auditory System)* is more sensitive than *HVS (Human Visual System)*, you are usually limited with audio steganography comparing to image steganography. There are not many detalied publications with *"Audio Steganography"* tag. Interests about hiding digital data inside audio files have tended into watermarking field. So I strongly suggest you to research whatever you are looking for as *"Audio Watermarking"*. You will find more contents related to watermarking.

**Few more words about Audio Steganography:**

LSB technique provides you more capacity to hide inside audio files, yet it will be very fragile to resist against any attacks such as mp3 compression. According to my experiences, *DSSS* and *Echo Hiding* methods are more robust comparing to *LSB Coding* and *Parity Coding*. DSSS provides a bit more capacity than Echo Hiding, but the noise is audible comparing to Echo Hiding.